# Error while retreving values from DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get title, count and percentage from table REPORT_VIEW_PAGE. That works fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, COUNT(TITLE) AS tot, ROUND(COUNT(TITLE)/(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REPORT_VIEW_PAGE), 4) AS per
FROM REPORT_VIEW_PAGE 
WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0'
GROUP BY TITLE
ORDER BY TITLE ASC
```

But if tried to retrieve ID and TYPE like

```
SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, ID, TYPE, COUNT(TITLE) AS tot, ROUND(COUNT(TITLE)/(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REPORT_VIEW_PAGE), 4) AS per
FROM REPORT_VIEW_PAGE 
WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0'
GROUP BY TITLE
ORDER BY TITLE ASC
```

i'm getting the error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 12 Column: 24

Can anyone help.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Clearly, if you add `id` and `type` to the `group by`, you will fix the problem.  But that is probably not the query you want.

Comment: In addition to what Gordon said, if you're doing a `group by` then the `distinct` is unnecessary, confusing and needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to group by the additional columns

```
SELECT TITLE, ID, TYPE, COUNT(TITLE) AS tot, ROUND(COUNT(TITLE)/(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REPORT_VIEW_PAGE), 4) AS per
FROM REPORT_VIEW_PAGE 
WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0'
GROUP BY TITLE, Id, TYPE
ORDER BY TITLE ASC
```

Comment: could yo mark as the correct answer please